# Flutter error "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase/auth/authscreen.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Home();
        } else {
          return AuthScreen();
        }
      },
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Dev dependencies

firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
firebase_core: ^1.4.0
firebase_database: ^8.0.1
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
google_fonts:
fluttertoast:

Answer (score 0):

you need to call

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

in the main method. And it will look like

```
Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(new MyApp());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

you need to add this

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).